# Getting 403 FORBIDDEN status code for HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException after upgrading to springboot 3.0.x

Tags: java, spring-boot

With spring boot `2.7.18` below testcase was passing

```java
@Test
    public void testInvalidMessage() {
        final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("user", "password")
                .postForEntity("/v1", "NOT_VALID_JSON", String.class);

        assertThat(responseEntity).isNotNull();
        assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
    }
```

Spring was sending `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` with `415` status code.

But after upgrading to spring boot `3.0.0`, for same test case getting `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` with `403` status code.

My Controller class is

```java
@RestController("MyController")
@RequestMapping(MyController.ENDPOINT)
public class MyController {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    public static final String ENDPOINT = "/v1";

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Operation(summary = "Requests for a particular operation.")
    public ResponseEntity<XYZ> requestGrant(@RequestBody XYZRequest xyzRequest, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Received request:\n{}", xyzRequest);

//other logic here
}
```

For `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` the response status code should be always `415` not `403`

Comment: 403 is *forbidden*, not *Unsupported Media Type*. Looks like changes with the authorization

Comment: disable any security related dependency to test the correct behaviour

Comment: Similarly for HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException also getting 403 instead of 406. When I ran my test in debug mode and it executes below code from RestTemplate.class
`response = request.execute()` the output is

```
024-02-07T12:15:08.865+05:30  WARN 3148 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation]
response.getStatusCode();
HttpStatus@291 "403 FORBIDDEN"
name:
"FORBIDDEN"
ordinal:
27
reasonPhrase:
"Forbidden"
series:
HttpStatus$Series@295
value:
403
```